# PHP curl write response final callback

Tags: php, curl, reverse-proxy

I am trying to develop a reverse proxy sever in PHP, and am using CURL for making the http requests.

I am using CURLOPT_WRITEFUNCTION to configure my write callback function.

`

```
function curlReadCallback(&$param, $body)
     if ($this->_buffered) {
                        $this->_buffer .= $body;}
// process($this_buffer) // On final call, i want to call this 
}
```

`

In this callback function, I create buffer of the response accumulated so far, and once all response has been given, I want to process the final response at once. The problem is that, I am not able to figure out how to know that this is the last callback, and now I can proceed with processing the full response.

Any help will be highly appreciated!

Answer (score 0):

Looks like your code just needs to count the number of requests it's making and compare with the responses received.

Given:

```
$this->requestsSent = 10;  // set to however many requests you send
$this->responsesReceived = 0;
```

You could use something like this:

```
function curlReadCallback(&$param, $body)
  $this->responsesReceived++;
  if ($this->_buffered) {
    $this->_buffer .= $body;
  }
  if ($this->responsesReceived == $this->requestsSent) {
    process($this->_buffer);
  }
}
```